# The Print command inserts unexpected characters inside string values when printing "pretty-printed" json string

Tags: ios, json, swift, hebrew

I want to print a pretty-printed representation of a JSON I get from the server.
The JSON has many string values in Hebrew.
I noticed that when the output is printed in the debug console, sometimes I see the symbol "327\" inserted inside some of the texts. The location is inconsistent.
Example:

```
  "Description" : "מעבדות קורונה",
  "DictionaryPlaceholder" : "ל\327דוגמא : ראש העין",
```

And if I print the RAW value of the same JSON, it isn't pretty but the string is correct:

```
  \"Description\":\"מעבדות קורונה\",\"DictionaryPlaceholder\":\"לדוגמא : ראש העין\",
```

The additional 327\ creates parsing issues when I copy the JSON from the console and try to parse it in other systems.

This is the relevant code:

```
private let separator = "\n"
private let terminator = "\n==========================================\n"

private func logNetworkResponse(_ response: URLResponse?, data: Data?, target: TargetType) -> String {
    var output = String()
    output.append("[\(date)]\(separator)")
    
    if let data = data {
        if let pretty = data.prettyJSON {
            output.append("\(target) (pretty-printed) Response: \(pretty)")
        } else if let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            output.append("\(target) (raw) Response: \(string))")
        }
    }
    
    output.append(terminator)
    return output
}

extension Data {
    var prettyJSON: String? {
        guard let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self) else {
            return nil
        }

        var pretty: Data?
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            pretty = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: [.prettyPrinted, .withoutEscapingSlashes])
        } else {
            pretty = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: [.prettyPrinted])
        }
        
        guard let pretty = pretty else {
            return nil
        }
        return String(data: pretty, encoding: .utf8)
    }
}
```

And this is how the output of logNetworkResponse() is printed:

```
public func didReceive(_ result: Result<Moya.Response, MoyaError>, target: TargetType) {
    var outputMessage: String?
    if case .success(let response) = result {
        
        // Attempt to parse the data for pretty printing only in QA Env
        if printNetworkActivity {
            outputMessage = logNetworkResponse(response.response, data: response.data, target: target)
        }
    } else {
        outputMessage = logNetworkResponse(nil, data: nil, target: target)
    }
    output(message: outputMessage)
}

private func output(message: String?) {
    if let message = message,
       printNetworkActivity {
            print(message)
    }
}
```

I want the pretty printed output to be valid and without random additional characters that messes it up. Does anybody know what is this symbol 327\ and why is is sometimes inserted inside the texts?

Comment: If you display this data elsewhere (e.g., write it to a file, or display it inside of a text view), do you still see that inserted into the string? It might help to narrow down whether this could be a display bug inside of the debug console, or whether those characters are actually making their way into the produced string.

Comment: @ItaiFerber When I add a breakpoint in output() and PO the message into the console (and copy the output into other editors etc), it looks valid. The only place I see the additional symbols is when using Print.

Comment: Interesting. Are you able to reproduce this in a small standalone block of code? For instance, if I copy your data from this question into a dictionary literal inside of a simple command-line app in Xcode 13.4.1, create a string using `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject...)` and `print` that string, I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Also, are you able to share what your data looks like before you call `prettyJSON` on it? It might be worth looking over the raw bytes in a hex editor just to confirm that there really isn't anything unexpected in there, because the `prettyJSON` goes through an additional parsing and reformatting process that might be handling an unexpected character in a surprising way.

Comment: (FWIW, I went over the non-pretty-printed `"DictionaryPlaceholder"` value string you posted character by character, but there doesn't appear to be anything hidden in there. It's theoretically possible that between copying the original data and posting it to SO something could have been removed, but it's impossible to know from our end. The string characters all check out.)